# Elasticsearch Curator unable to connect with AWS ElasticSearch service

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

From a server on AWS, I push data into AWS ES service.
This data appears on Kibana just fine.
I am also able to perform cleanup via cURL commands from this machine.
However, no machine of mine is able to run ElasticSearch Curator successfully and connect to AWS ES.

```
...jects/elasticsearch-curator❯ curator --host HOSTNAME.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com delete indices --older-than 12 --time-unit days --timestring %Y.%m.%d
2016-12-18 16:54:08,631 INFO      Job starting: delete indices
2016-12-18 16:58:10,143 ERROR     Connection failure.
```

My access policy allows me to access this machine:

```
~❯ curl HOSTNAME.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com
{
  "name" : "Exodus",
  "cluster_name" : "########",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.3.2",
    "build_hash" : "##########",
    "build_timestamp" : "2016-11-14T15:59:50Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

and run commands:

```
~❯ curl -XDELETE 'HOSTNAME.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/2016-11*'
{"acknowledged":true}%
```

I am using the version of [ES curator stated to be working with AWS ES](https://github.com/elastic/curator#compatibility-matrix):

```
...jects/elasticsearch-curator❯ pip list | grep curator
elasticsearch-curator (3.5.1)
```

As per answer (1) I added a port setting: "--port 80"
the connection still fails, just much faster:

```
curator --host HOSTNAME --port 80 delete indices --older-than 12 --time-unit days --timestring %Y.%m.%d
2016-12-19 08:28:18,309 INFO      Job starting: delete indices
2016-12-19 08:28:18,324 ERROR     Connection failure.
```

and here is the output for debug mode:

```
2016-12-19 11:25:59,247 DEBUG         curator.api.filter         get_date_regex:157  regex = \l\o\g\s\t\a\s\h\-\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}
2016-12-19 11:25:59,247 DEBUG          curator.cli.utils        filter_callback:195  REGEX = (?P<date>\l\o\g\s\t\a\s\h\-\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})
2016-12-19 11:25:59,247 DEBUG          curator.cli.utils        filter_callback:198  Added filter: {'pattern': '(?P<date>\\l\\o\\g\\s\\t\\a\\s\\h\\-\\d{4}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{2})', 'value': 12, 'groupname': 'date', 'time_unit': 'days', 'timestring': u'logstash-%Y.%m.%d', 'method': 'older_than'}
2016-12-19 11:25:59,247 DEBUG          curator.cli.utils        filter_callback:199  New list of filters: [{'pattern': '(?P<date>\\l\\o\\g\\s\\t\\a\\s\\h\\-\\d{4}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{2})', 'value': 12, 'groupname': 'date', 'time_unit': 'days', 'timestring': u'logstash-%Y.%m.%d', 'method': 'older_than'}]
2016-12-19 11:25:59,248 INFO      curator.cli.index_selection                indices:62   Job starting: delete indices
2016-12-19 11:25:59,248 DEBUG     curator.cli.index_selection                indices:65   Params: {'url_prefix': u'', 'http_auth': None, 'dry_run': False, 'certificate': None, 'loglevel': u'INFO', 'logformat': u'default', 'client_cert': None, 'host': u'HOSTNAME', 'quiet': False, 'timeout': 30, 'debug': True, 'use_ssl': False, 'logfile': None, 'master_only': False, 'port': 80, 'ssl_no_validate': False, 'client_key': None}
2016-12-19 11:25:59,248 DEBUG          curator.cli.utils             get_client:114  kwargs = {'url_prefix': u'', 'http_auth': None, 'dry_run': False, 'certificate': None, 'loglevel': u'INFO', 'host': u'HOSTNAME', 'quiet': False, 'port': 80, 'logformat': u'default', 'timeout': 30, 'debug': True, 'use_ssl': False, 'logfile': None, 'master_only': False, 'client_cert': None, 'ssl_no_validate': False, 'client_key': None}
2016-12-19 11:25:59,248 DEBUG         urllib3.util.retry               from_int:191  Converted retries value: False -> Retry(total=False, connect=None, read=None, redirect=0)
2016-12-19 11:25:59,248 DEBUG     urllib3.connectionpool              _new_conn:212  Starting new HTTP connection (1): HOSTNAME
2016-12-19 11:25:59,584 DEBUG     urllib3.connectionpool          _make_request:400  http://HOSTNAME:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 None
2016-12-19 11:25:59,586 INFO               elasticsearch    log_request_success:66   GET http://HOSTNAME:80/ [status:200 request:0.338s]
2016-12-19 11:25:59,586 DEBUG              elasticsearch    log_request_success:68   > None
2016-12-19 11:25:59,587 DEBUG              elasticsearch    log_request_success:69   <
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" charset="utf-8">
<head>
<title>Sign In</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<style>
body {
         font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
color: #333;
background: #f0f0f0;
}
.signin {
    display:block;
margin:20px auto;
max-width:400px;
background: #fff;
border:1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 10px;
padding: 20px;
}
.center {
    text-align:center;
}
.btn {
    color: #fff;
        background-color: #428bca;
border: 1px solid #357ebd;
            -webkit-border-radius: 4;
-moz-border-radius: 4;
border-radius: 4px;
font-size: 14px;
padding: 6px 12px;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #3071a9;
        border-color: #285e8e;
ext-decoration: none;
}
label {
    display: inline-block;
max-width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 5px;
font-weight: 700;
}
input {
    display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 34px;
padding: 6px 12px;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
color: #555;
background-color: #fff;
background-image: none;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
-webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
-o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
margin:0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
footer {
    display:block;
font-size:10px;
color:#aaa;
text-align:center;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
footer a {
    display:inline-block;
height:25px;
line-height:25px;
color:#aaa;
text-decoration:underline;
}
footer a:hover {
    color:#aaa;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="signin center">
<form method="GET" action="/oauth2/start">
<input type="hidden" name="rd" value="/">

<p>Authenticate using @crosswise.com</p>

<button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in with a Google Account</button><br/>
</form>
</div>


<div class="signin">
<form method="POST" action="/oauth2/sign_in">
<input type="hidden" name="rd" value="/">
<label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="10"><br/>
<label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="10"><br/>
<button type="submit" class="btn">Sign In</button>
</form>
</div>

<script>
if (window.location.hash) {
(function() {
var inputs = document.getElementsByName('rd');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
inputs[i].value += window.location.hash;
}
})();
}
</script>
<footer>

Secured with <a href="https://github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy#oauth2_proxy">OAuth2 Proxy</a> version 2.2.0-alpha

</footer>
</body>
</html>

2016-12-19 11:25:59,587 ERROR          curator.cli.utils             get_client:140  Connection failure.
```

So I added a few diagnostic lines in the appropriate place in utils.py:

```
try:
    client = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch(**kwargs)
    check_version(client)
    # Verify the version is acceptable.
    logger.debug('version is acceptable')
    check_master(client, master_only=master_only)
    # Verify "master_only" status, if applicable
    logger.debug('Verify "master_only" status')
    return client
except Exception as e:
    import traceback
    logger.error('Connection failure.')
    logger.error(e)
    traceback.print_exc()
    sys.exit(1)
```

and we get:

```
2016-12-19 11:42:37,345 ERROR          curator.cli.utils             get_client:143  Connection failure.
2016-12-19 11:42:37,345 ERROR          curator.cli.utils             get_client:144  Unknown mimetype, unable to deserialize: text/html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gilzellner/.virtualenvs/temp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/curator/cli/utils.py", line 134, in get_client
    check_version(client)
  File "/Users/gilzellner/.virtualenvs/temp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/curator/cli/utils.py", line 89, in check_version
    version_number = get_version(client)
  File "/Users/gilzellner/.virtualenvs/temp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/curator/api/utils.py", line 202, in get_version
    version = client.info()['version']['number']
  File "/Users/gilzellner/.virtualenvs/temp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 69, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/gilzellner/.virtualenvs/temp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 220, in info
    return self.transport.perform_request('GET', '/', params=params)
  File "/Users/gilzellner/.virtualenvs/temp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 357, in perform_request
    data = self.deserializer.loads(data, headers.get('content-type'))
  File "/Users/gilzellner/.virtualenvs/temp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/serializer.py", line 74, in loads
    raise SerializationError('Unknown mimetype, unable to deserialize: %s' % mimetype)
SerializationError: Unknown mimetype, unable to deserialize: text/html
```

Answer (score 0):

Curator is attempting to connect to port 9200, the default ES port.  AWS ES is on port 80. Add `--port 80` to your command line.

Comment: curator --host HOSTNAME --port 80 delete indices --older-than 12 --time-unit days --timestring %Y.%m.%d
    2016-12-19 08:28:18,309 INFO      Job starting: delete indices
    2016-12-19 08:28:18,324 ERROR     Connection failure.

Comment: so err, didnt work. but it does fail faster, which is an improvement :)

Comment: Try running tcpdump while you run curator vs curl, see what it is doing different connection-wise.